# Rails, has_many with foreign key, how to hook up belongs to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

My User model has the following lines:

```
  has_many :social_ids 
  has_many :friend_ids,  :class_name => "SocialId"
```

And my SocialId model has:

```
belongs_to :user
```

This allows me to do things like

user1.social_ids << social_id1
user2.social_ids << social_id2
user1.friend_ids << social_id2

However, I didn't realize (mistake on my part) that now both social_id1 and social_id2 both have user1 as their user.

This is obviously wrong, but I can't figure out how to hook up a belongs to correctly in this case.

```
belongs_to :friend_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'friend_user_id'
```

doesn't look right...and how will it know to go into the friend_ids section of user rather than social id?

Am I just completely confused?

Edit:

I think I was at least partially confused.  A social ID shouldn't BELONG_TO a friend, it should be a HABTM relationship (a single social id can be friends with multiple users which each have multiple social_id friends)

Comment: I think you want to be careful with how you namespace your models. Can you think of better names? Obviously it might be best to have just a `Friend` model, and maybe a `Social` model?

Comment: While that might be true, a "friend" is just a social ID that a user is connected to (in my design, a social ID is not necessarily connected to a User, it makes sense in context).  Regardless of my namespace, though, is it just inappropriate to have two sets of a single model with has_many and belongs_to?  A Boss might have two arrays of employees, for example, which are identical except in how a Boss interacts with them.